# Android app crashing on viewing code blocks

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Version 1.0.53

Viewing questions with code blocks is fine, until I click on the code to scroll. Crashes every time, even after rebooting the phone.

Example question: [Does using the same drive letter for DFS replication on Windows Server 2012 R2 cause any known issues?](https://serverfault.com/q/661060/23513)

OnePlus One phone, latest CM
Stock nexus 5 updated

Comment: For what it's worth, i'm getting the same issue on a stock, updated Nexus 5

Comment: @shadow this bug is for any size code block, even the one liners. As well, it's past version 1.0.23

Comment: Still, sounds like same root cause which wasn't yet fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't related to the similar bug mentioned in the comments. It's due to the new theming we're using for Material Design of as of version 1.0.53.

This crash is fixed as of version 1.0.54, coming out later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Crash is happening again for me.

Comment: @Doorknob yep I've been tracking the crash logs, this is the biggest one on the newest version so far. Trying to find the underlying cause.